# The book of Jasher

Tags: apocrypha, extra-biblical, jasher

Have any transcripts  been discovered?  Who wrote this book? The book is mentioned in Joshua and was apparently an important book during their days. What happened to the book?

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing. If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: @FilipeMerker I don't think this is a duplicate, though it is closely related.

Comment: Several different things are called the "Book of Jasher". You'll need to specify exactly what you're referring to.